# Xamarin - Change colors of TimePicker from CustomRenderer class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How can i change colors of TimePicker from CustomRender.

This is my custom renderer class but didn't work.

```
public class CustomTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);   
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);  
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What color do you want to change ? In your custom renderer,you just change the Control's color(which implement `EditText` in the native android platform,refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers#views)).

Here are some of the color changes for TimePicker，create the `Theme.picker` style in your `Resources/values/styles` in Android Project.

```
<style name="Theme.picker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
   //background color
   <item name="android:background">#FFC107</item>
   //Title background color
   <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
   //text color
   <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
   //edittext color
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
</style>
```

and add it into your `MainTheme`:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">

</style>

<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  ...
  <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/Theme.picker</item>
</style>
```

the effect like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to change this colors dynamically but styles.xml doesn't change programmatically.That's why i asked this question.

Comment: If you want to change its color dynamically,you need create  a your custom timepicker dialog,and set the properties of NumberPicker with reflection.We usually configure its color in style.

Comment: I changed my UI and no more don't need timepicker dialog